# Why is this dynamically generated HTML not being displayed in a UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have HTML I am generating in my app. I know it's valid because I ran it through W3Schools "edit and try it".  It performs exactly as I designed it.

Here is the definition of the website in the header file:

```
@interface ReportViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>  {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *reportWebView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *reportWebView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *html;

- (void) generateReport;
- (void) Alert: (NSString *) title andData: (NSString *) errorMsg; 

@end
```

Here is where I finish creating the HTML and try to display it:

```
        //  now do the table
        [html appendString:@"<div><table border class=\"boldtable\">" 
        "<tr BGCOLOR=\"ADDAFE\">" 
        "<th>STA&nbsp;</th><th>BS&nbsp;</th><th>HI&nbsp;</th><th>FS&nbsp;</th><th>ELEV&nbsp;</th><th>Desc</th>" 
        "</tr><p>"];
    }    

    //  finally, end the table, etc.
    [html appendString:@"</table></div></body></html>"];

 //   UIWebView *reportWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    //[reportWebView loadHTMLString: html baseURL:nil];
    [self.reportWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
}
```

As you can see, I have tried several different variations of displaying the HTML string.  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Where are you appending the string to? Is it past the closing <body> tag maybe?

Comment: No, the final HTML string is valid, as I mentioned initially.  I do believe it has something to do with the way I'm trying to display it in the UIWebView.  I have done this before with a text file, but never with dynamically generated HTML.

Comment: Why dont you try to insert it with JavaScript? You can use the adjacentHTML dom method to insert the html...

Comment: I don't see what that would accomplish... this is supposed to work, and I'd like to know what is wrong with the way I'm doing it now.  Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Maybe the way you insert it doesn't trigger a page refresh to load the new HTML, so maybe the DOM method would trigger this. just an idea.

Comment: I just ran a test using the html file... it doesn't display either... looking to see why....

Comment: Are you sure self.reportWebView is not null?

Comment: `reportWebView` is an `IBOutlet`, indicating that it's created in an xib. Is the outlet connected? Is the nib loaded? What's with the commented-out `UIWebView *reportWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];`? Is this your exact code? Are you creating a local variable `reportWebView` that's shadowing the ivar?

Comment: Since reportWebView is an IBOutlet, just like lulius Caesar pointed out.  Make sure it is indeed connected properly to the xib in IBbuilder.

Comment: Illius: pls respond with your comment as the answer...that's exactly what it was.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Iulius Caesar</del> Jacques Cousteau gave the correct answer [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216973/why-is-this-dynamically-generated-html-not-being-displayed-in-a-uiwebview/10285709#comment13124192_10216973):

> `reportWebView` is an `IBOutlet`, indicating that it's created in an xib. Is the outlet connected? Is the nib loaded? What's with the commented-out `UIWebView *reportWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];`? Is this your exact code? Are you creating a local variable `reportWebView` that's shadowing the ivar?

but never came back to set it, therefore I am answering it for him.

Comment: I didn't see your reply until now (cleaning up old comments) because you didn't use the `@` in your comment: `@Iulius`. No problem, though. You should probably make it clearer in this answer _which_ part of my comment was the issue, since I made a couple of points.